# Set working directory for script

Tags: bash

I have a script in /A/B/script.sh. When called, it needs to operate on files in /X/Y/Z. How can I set a working directory specifically *for* the script, *in* the script?

Comment: Note: I know I can call it manually with (cd /X/Y/Z; ./script.sh), but I need the script to be run routinely in a crontab

Comment: crontab actually takes a string to run with `/bin/sh -c "yourstring"` (replacing `/bin/sh` if your crontab provides its own `SHELL` variable), so it is not in fact limited to one command at a time.

Comment: and btw, if you're going to be doing it in parens like that, use `exec`: `(cd /X/Y/Z && exec ./script.sh)` -- that way the cost you pay to spawn the subshell that the parens ask for is evened out by consuming that subshell via an `exec`, rather than running your `script.sh` as a subprocess of the subshell that is itself a subprocess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a `cd` statement in the script, just like you'd type to set your working directory from an interactive bash shell.

Comment: Actually -- *in* the script, it should have error handling. ie. `cd /X/Y/Z || exit` -- a human running things interactively will notice when a `cd` fails, a script will otherwise modify files in the wrong directory. See https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2164